# Dictionary comprehension - Get the values for each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Context: I'd like to create a dictionary with "Variable:values" pairs. The variable has a multindex like this:

```
   Sexo
   Masculino Feminino
0   4245.0  4620.0
1   4274.0  4655.0
2   4304.5  4689.5
3   4322.0  4708.5
4   4318.0  4717.5
5   4288.0  4710.5
6   4247.5  4683.5
7   4224.5  4650.5
8   4223.5  4613.5
9   4191.0  4567.0
10  4133.7  4546.9
11  4093.6  4550.1
12  4079.0  4551.5
13  4070.5  4562.6
```

And I'm creating the dictionary using a dict comprehension:

```
dict_boxplot = {col:val for (col,val) in zip(subcolumns,df_var.iloc[:,1])}
```

Where `subcolumns` are simply the names "Masculino" and "Feminino". How cold I make a dictionary with this format : {'Masculino': [value1,value2,value3...], 'Feminino': [value1,value2,value3...]} where `value1`, etc are the values from each column?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't use a dict comprehension here, btw. `{k:v for k,v in whatever}` should just be `dict(whatever)`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate only on column names, then collect the column and convert to a list

```
x = {col: df[col].to_list() for col in ['Masculino', 'Feminino']}
```

Or use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to help you

```
x = {k: list(column.values()) for k, column in df.to_dict().items()}
```

---

Helper code

```
import pandas as pd
values = {'Masculino': [4245.0, 4274.0, 4304.5, 4322.0, 4318.0, 4288.0, 4247.5,
                        4224.5, 4223.5, 4191.0, 4133.7, 4093.6, 4079.0, 4070.5],
          'Feminino': [4620.0, 4655.0, 4689.5, 4708.5, 4717.5, 4710.5, 4683.5,
                       4650.5, 4613.5, 4567.0, 4546.9, 4550.1, 4551.5, 4562.6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(values)

x = {col: df[col].to_list() for col in ['Masculino', 'Feminino']}
print(x)  # {'Masculino': [4245.0, ..., 4070.5], 'Feminino': [4620.0, ..., 4562.6]}

x = {k: list(column.values()) for k, column in df.to_dict().items()}
print(x)  # {'Masculino': [4245.0, ..., 4070.5], 'Feminino': [4620.0, ..., 4562.6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`to_dict('list')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df.to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'Masculino': [4245.0, 4274.0, 4304.5, 4322.0, 4318.0, 4288.0, 4247.5, 4224.5, 4223.5, 4191.0, 4133.7, 4093.6, 4079.0, 4070.5],
 'Feminino': [4620.0, 4655.0, 4689.5, 4708.5, 4717.5, 4710.5, 4683.5, 4650.5, 4613.5, 4567.0, 4546.9, 4550.1, 4551.5, 4562.6]
}
```

Comment: Hello, @mozway I've posted a new question since I did a poor job explaining the goal in this question